# How to save the increment/decrement state?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-studio

So my question is how do I save the state for the increment and decrement state for example I set a number to 10 then I decrement the number to 9. So let's say I exit the application, I want the number to save to 9 even after I exit the application. So how do I do that? Here's an example of my code.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import 'homepage.dart';

class AddParking extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddParking({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Add Parking';


    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        drawer: NavigationDrawer(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(appTitle),
        ),
        body: addParkingForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class addParkingForm extends StatefulWidget{
  @override

  addParkingFormState createState() {

    return addParkingFormState();
  }
}

class addParkingFormState extends State <addParkingForm> {
  String userID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  final TextEditingController parkingname= TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController parkinglevel= TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController parkingsection= TextEditingController();
  final myUuid = const Uuid().v4();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey=GlobalKey ();
  int number = 10;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Total Spots Left : ' + number.toString() ) ,
          TextFormField(
            controller: parkinglevel,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
              hintText: 'Parking Level ',
              labelText: 'Parking Level',
            ),
            validator: (String? text){
              if (text == null || text.isEmpty){
                return 'Please enter parking level';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: parkingsection,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
              hintText: 'Parking Section ',
              labelText: 'Parking Section',
            ),
            validator: (String? text){
              if (text == null || text.isEmpty){
                return 'Please enter a parking section place';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: parkingname,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
              hintText: 'Enter parking number',
              labelText: 'Parking number',
            ),
            validator: (String? text){
              if (text == null || text.isEmpty){
                return 'Please enter parking number';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),

          Container (
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, top: 40.0),
            child:
            ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Submit'),

                onPressed: ()
                async {
                  setState(() {
                    number--;
                  });
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    int total = 1;
                    String message;
                    try {

                      final collection =
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Parking');
                      await collection.doc().set({
                        'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                        'parking' : parkingname.text,
                        'level' : parkinglevel.text,
                        'section' : parkingsection.text,
                        'parkID' : myUuid,
                      });
                      total -= 1;

                      message = 'Success';

                  } catch (_) {
                      message = 'Error when sending feedback';
                    }
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
                  }
                }
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

Comment: Do you want that value to persist an app uninstall/storage cleared, or should it go back to the default value on a new install?

Comment: i want the value to continue to the last state after the apps are closed @DanHarms

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The reason for my question is local storage options will achieve what you're looking for, but if the user deletes the app you will lose the data as well. If it has to survive app installs you'd need a cloud solution.

Comment: lets remove the possible of the user if it deletes the app. I just want it to continue to the last state when the user close the app only

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend looking into hive: https://pub.dev/packages/hive. Save your value to a box each time it changes.

Answer (score 1):

you should use this package https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

you can save any type of primitive type in device shared preferences, but be careful it's not secure.

```
// Obtain shared preferences.
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

// Save an integer value to 'counter' key.
await prefs.setInt('counter', counterValue);

// Get value of counter
prefs.getInt('counter');
```

steps to solve your problem:

1. every time you changed the value of the counter you should save it in the device shared preferences.
2. first time when you open the app you should fetch the value of counter from the shared preferencs.

here is example with flutter counter app.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const String _counterKey = 'COUNTER';
  int _counter = 0;
  late final SharedPreferences sp;
  late bool isFetchingCounterValue;
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();   
      WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async { //make sure that build function is finished then setState
      setState(() {
      isFetchingCounterValue = true;  
      });
      sp = await  SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       setState(() {
        isFetchingCounterValue = false;
        _counter = sp.getInt(_counterKey) ?? 0; //0 if it's first time you are opening the app
      });
    });
    
     
  }

  Future<void> _incrementCounter() async {
    _counter++;
    await sp.setInt(_counterKey, _counter);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: isFetchingCounterValue ? const CircularProgressIndicator() : Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

of course if you want save modeling and more than just Integer, and String, to create local database. consider this package https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite